# Parsing strings in variable and store them to a new variable

Tags: c++, parsing

I need to parse the following, which is stored in a variable, and extract only Names. These names should be placed in a new variable (all together separated by **dot** (.)). Any ideas?

```
Name : Mike Anderson\n
Age : 43\n
Name : Andie Jameson\n
Age : 35\n
```

The expected output should be a variable with content: `Mike Anderson.Andie Jameson`

Thank you.

Comment: Treat them as a long string and extract based on `Name :`.

Comment: That's the question :P how do i do that in case of a variable...

Comment: Is it "Do my homework ?" if not show some _relevant_ code that you have tried. And yes, by relevant I mean not the "Hello World" code. Don't just open a file and say this I tried.

Comment: lol, i just need a method of getting out all names out of a variable mister. I did it with _popen and i think it doesn't fit my needs so i would like to have an idea on how on earth could be possible by using a variable. Is asking so wrong in here? Could any of you answer to ANY question without playing the "you little skiddo"-game? Pf... Ignore the question please. Thank you very much. And no, it isn't any "do my homework" request. I am trying to learn something. Without your help as i see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There will be many useful methods for your situation. 
This code is just one of them. I used `std::istringstream`, `string::find()`.

```
int main()
{
  //Originally, each data is from your source.
  //but, this is just sample.
  std::istringstream input;
  input.str("Name : Mike Anderson\nAge : 43\nName : Andie Jameson\nAge : 35\n");

  //to find pattern
  std::string name_pattern = "Name : ";

  std::size_t found = std::string::npos;
 for (std::string line; std::getline(input, line); ) {
    found = line.find(name_pattern);
    if (found!=std::string::npos)
    {
        //write on file for 'directory'
        std::string only_name(line, found + name_pattern.length() );
        std::cout << "\nName : " << only_name;

        continue;
    }
  }

  getchar();
}
```

This code will print below like,

[image]

Comment: Not only does that not produce the output the OP asked for, it appears  to invoke things considerably more advanced than the OP might understand (based on the limited information made available by them)